# Exporting org file breaks when upgrading to orgmode 8.3

Tags: org-mode, org-export

My orgmode was recently updated to the recent 8.3, and I found that I can't export my [init.org](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/john2x/emacs.d/master/init.org) file as HTML any more.

I'm getting the following output in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
org-babel-exp process emacs-lisp at line 34...
org-babel-exp process emacs-lisp at line 44...
org-babel-exp process emacs-lisp at line 51...
... hundreds of lines like these ...
apply: Wrong type argument: listp, #("John's Emacs Config" 0 19 (:parent (#0)))
```

It seems that's it's having trouble parsing some of the headers. I tried removing the `TITLE` and `AUTHOR` headers and it was able to export.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the new Org being compiled while an older version is loaded.  Try installing in a clean session without Org loaded.

Answer (score 25):

The full sequence of steps that worked for me:

- From the command line:

  - Run emacs without loading the init file: `emacs -q`
- In emacs:

  - run `C-u M-x org-reload`
  - Use `package-list-packages` to uninstall `org`: select it then `d x`
  - Use `package-list-packages` to reinstall `org`: select it then `i x`

After restarting emacs, everything worked.

Comment: `C-u M-x org-reload` was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem with: `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.5 (Build 15F34)) of 2016-07-26` and `Org-mode version 8.3.5 (8.3.5-elpa)`.

I was able to get around it by removing any of my "titles" or any line it complained about.

For instance removing this block, i was able to export to both `ox-reveal` and `ox-twbs`:

```
#+TITLE:  My Emacs Configuration
#+AUTHOR: JJ Asghar
#+EMAIL:  jjasghar@email.com
```

Comment: I should say, also following up with the above answer resolved my issue too.