# Orgmode character export to latex pdf

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am exporting a block of code

```
#+begin_lstlisting
cut -d \' | grep http://
#+end_lstlisting
```

But the org export to latex replaces the backslash with `$\backslash$` and the http:// string with `\url{http://}`.

I have tried the export options

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil -:nil tex:verbatim
```

But they haven't done the trick. Any suggestions would be helpful.

I am using orgmode 8.2.10 on Emacs 25.1.50.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of `org code blocks` and `noweb` to get the results you expected.

1. **Create a empty `org code block` for `shell` command <kbd>C-c</kbd>  <kbd>C-v</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd>  <kbd>org</kbd>**

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC org
   #+END_SRC
   ```
2. **Assign a `#+NAME:` to block then add `:results latex replace :exports none` headers.**

   ```
   #+NAME: latex-shell-script
   #+BEGIN_SRC org :results latex replace :exports none
   #+END_SRC
   ```
3. **Add an empty line into org block and place cursor on empty line.**

   ```
   #+NAME: latex-shell-script
   #+BEGIN_SRC org :results latex replace :exports none
   _
   #+END_SRC
   ```
4. **Open empty org code block for editing using <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> then create `sh` code block**

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC sh
     cut -d \' | grep http://
   #+END_SRC
   ```
5. **Save edited code with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> then close edit buffer with  <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>**

   ```
   #+NAME: latex-shell-script
   #+BEGIN_SRC org :results latex replace :exports none
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC sh
     cut -d \' | grep http://
    ,#+END_SRC
   #+END_SRC
   ```
6. **Create a empty `org code block` for `1stlisting` block <kbd>C-c</kbd>  <kbd>C-v</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd>  <kbd>org</kbd>**

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC org
   #+END_SRC
   ```
7. **Add `:noweb yes :results latex replace  :exports results` headers to empty block**

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC org :noweb yes :results latex replace  :exports results 
   #+END_SRC
   ```
8. **Add an empty line into org block and place cursor on empty line.**

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC org :noweb yes :results latex replace  :exports results 
   _
   #+END_SRC
   ```
9. **Open empty org code block for editing using <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> then enter the following code.**

   ```
   #+begin_lstlisting
   <<latex-shell-script()>>
   #+end_lstlisting
   ```
10. **Save edited code with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> then close edit buffer with  <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>**

    ```
    #+BEGIN_SRC org :noweb yes :results latex replace  :exports results 
      ,#+begin_lstlisting
      <<latex-shell-script()>>
      ,#+end_lstlisting
    #+END_SRC
    ```
11. **Use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> to export your code blocks to latex and you should see results similar to code listed below.**

    ```
    \begin{lstlisting}
    \begin{verbatim}
    cut -d \' | grep http://
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{lstlisting}
    ```

Hope that helped!

---

> Code Tested using
>
> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   org-version: 8.3.2

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried running this and I got a "No org-babel-execute function for org!". I tried adding this 
    (org-babel-do-load-languages
     'org-bable-load-languages
     '((org . t)))
but I still got the issue. Is there something else you configured?

Comment: @Jesse - Oh no! I'm sure this just a configuration issue because I've been able to do this using earlier versions of org-mode. Did you type in new config by hand or did you use the customization menu? Could it be a typo? Another alternative *might* be that this setting is read at startup so restarting emacs will refresh it. I doubt this is the case though. Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: I found one problem of mine, I had `org-bable-load-languages instead of `org-babel-load-languages. After that when I run the latex export I am asked twice if I want to "Evaluate this org code block (latex-shell-script) on your system?". I answer yes both times and then I am asked if I want to "Evaluate this org code block on your system?", to which I answer yes. Then I get "Wrong type argument: listp, #("Jesse Millwood" 0 14 (:parent (#0)))". I assume this corresponds to my "#+AUTHOR: Jesse Millwood" line. I have never had an issue with this before. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Actually after updating my org package by this [link](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/exporting-org-file-breaks-when-upgrading-to-orgmode-8-3) Everything worked fine. Thank you so much for your answer and follow up comments!

Comment: Sorry, actually it ran, but the output is a bit odd. I have      

#+NAME: latex-shell-script
     #+BEGIN_SRC org :results latex replace
            ,#+BEGIN_SRC sh
            cut -d \' | grep http://
            ,#+END_SRC
     #+END_SRC
     #+BEGIN_SRC org :noweb yes :results latex replace :exports results
     ,#+begin_lstlisting
     <<latex-shell-script()>>
     ,#+end_lstlisting
     #+END_SRC
But it outputs:
\begin{verbatim}
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
cut -d \' | grep http://
#+END_SRC
\end{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{verbatim}
cut -d \' | grep http://
\end{verbatim}
\end{lstlisting}

Comment: @Jesse - Sorry my mistake! First code org block is missing ` :exports none` header. I'll update the instructions! Thanks for catching my error!

Comment: @Jesse - I updated instructions in my answer. Please let me know if that fixed your issue. It should.

Comment: That gives the output you said it would, Thank you! I think now I am having an issue with the `lstlisting` environment, as it is showing the `verbatim` environment on pdf export but that is, I believe, an issue with the latex environment and not orgmode.