# Exporting org file breaks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, debugging

I have a similar problem to the one asked here [Exporting org file breaks when upgrading to orgmode 8.3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/exporting-org-file-breaks-when-upgrading-to-orgmode-8-3), org-mode cannot export org files and raises this error:

```
apply: Wrong type argument: listp, #("Peter's Emacs Config" 0 19 (:parent (#0)))
```

The solution **aw** has given works for me, that is, `C-u M-x org-reload`.

Nonetheless, I wanted to know why Emacs broke and how to fix such problems once and for all. Have not found anything on the Internet or on the GitHub page of org-mode.

I am using *GNU Emacs 26.0.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8)
 of 2016-10-26* and org-version *9.0.5*.

Answer (score 1):

1. The error message says that function `apply` raised an error because it expected a list argument but was passed a (propertized) string argument.
2. `C-h f apply` tells you that the last argument must be a list. It is likely that the last argument passed to `apply` is the string that is cited in the error message.
3. You can see more if you set variable `debug-on-error` to `t` and then provoke the error again. That will show you a backtrace of function calls. The backtrace will be more helpful if you first load the source code where the error is raised, that is, the `*.el` file, not the `*.elc` file, which is byte-compiled.
4. The backtrace will show you which function called `apply` erroneously.  You can use `M-x debug-on-entry FUN`, where `FUN` is that function. That will open the interactive debugger each time function `FUN` is called.  You can use `d` in the debugger to step through evaluation. Or you can use `c` to skip through an evaluation without going into its details.