# Export from Org Mode to LaTeX doesn't accept the option #+title:

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When I try an export from Org Mode to LaTeX I get the following error message:

> apply: Wrong type argument: listp, #("Aufgabe 3" 0 9 (:parent (#0)))

The problem comes from the option

> #+title: *title*.

I don't have any special settings for LaTeX-Export.

Where does this error message come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way too late of course. Well, I had the same problem with the `AUTHOR` header, and found a [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/exporting-org-file-breaks-when-upgrading-to-orgmode-8-3).

`C-u M-x org-reload` solved my problem.